# is there any way in django to list all devices a user logged in?

Tags: python, django, authentication, logging

I am trying to list all the device and their locations on which a user account is logged in . similar to login activity of instagram, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to install pyyamln ua-parser, user-agents and django-user-agents

```
pip install pyyaml ua-parser user-agents
pip install django-user-agents
```

Then add add django-user-agents to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_user_agents',
    ...
]
```

Then add the User middleware to your middlewares list:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
]
```

Now you can use the following methods to get information you need, then you can store them in a database:

```
def my_view(request):

    # Let's assume that the visitor uses an iPhone...
    request.user_agent.is_mobile # returns True
    request.user_agent.is_tablet # returns False
    request.user_agent.is_touch_capable # returns True
    request.user_agent.is_pc # returns False
    request.user_agent.is_bot # returns False

    # Accessing user agent's browser attributes
    request.user_agent.browser  # returns Browser(family=u'Mobile Safari', version=(5, 1), version_string='5.1')
    request.user_agent.browser.family  # returns 'Mobile Safari'
    request.user_agent.browser.version  # returns (5, 1)
    request.user_agent.browser.version_string   # returns '5.1'

    # Operating System properties
    request.user_agent.os  # returns OperatingSystem(family=u'iOS', version=(5, 1), version_string='5.1')
    request.user_agent.os.family  # returns 'iOS'
    request.user_agent.os.version  # returns (5, 1)
    request.user_agent.os.version_string  # returns '5.1'

    # Device properties
    request.user_agent.device  # returns Device(family='iPhone')
    request.user_agent.device.family  # returns 'iPhone'
```

PS: you can also use memcached to speed up this process:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```